# linear search for multiple integers

Tags: java, algorithm, search, linear-search

Im trying to implement a linear search for an array of integers that if the number is a multiply of 3 its going to print the index of the number in the array and if there is no any number that is a multiple of 3 its going to return -1 
im trying to implement this without using a method for it and my problem is how im going to do the printing/returning of -1? 
knowing that my code is

```
int[] a = {3, 5, 22, 7, 9, 8, 21};
System.out.println("the index of 3 multiplies is" );
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) { 
    if (a[i] % 3 == 0) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a `foundIndex` variable, initialized to -1. Continue to loop only if it's still -1. Print the value of the variable after the loop.

Comment: You do not need the continue statement.

Comment: Why not having the function return an array containing the indexes of the numbers that are multiple of three, and null otherwise. You then do the printing separately.

Comment: can you please help me by showing it in codes

Comment: I've understood part of the idea your trying the explain but I'm not sure if its right. the idea I didnt get is how I'm going to check "if its still -1"? the problem is that if i am printing it out of the is will print it any way even if there is a multiple of 3

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < a.length && foundIndex == -1; i++)`. Of course, you should set foundIndex inside the loop with... the found index. So that after the loop, it's still -1 if you haven't found the index, and it's the found index if you found it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `boolean found = false` and set it to `true` if the algorithm found a multiply of 3. After the for loop you could ask for result.

Comment: what if the purpose? i didn't use it in a while or something.. could you explain more please?

Comment: You figured it out by yourself in the solution below, thats exactly what i meant ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] a = {3, 5, 22, 7, 9, 8, 21};
int multipleOfThree = 0;
System.out.println("the index of 3 multiplies is" );
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) { 
    if (a[i] % 3 == 0) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
        multipleOfThree++;
    }
}

if( multipleOfThree == 0 ){
    System.out.println(-1);
}
```

I think this is what you are looking for. If you want to use a method, instead of printing the multipleOfThree, you should return it.

Comment: thanks!! I have used similar way ti solve it!!  yours worked too!

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] a = {1,5,22,7,52,8,20};
   System.out.println("the index of 3 multiplies is" );
    boolean found = false; 
   for(int i = 0; i<a.length;i++){ 
   if(a[i]%3==0){
    found = true; 
    System.out.println(i+"  ");
   }
  }
   if(!found){
    System.out.println("-1");
   }
  }``
```